# Specify an array without jQuery and without NodeLists

Tags: nodelist

Challenge = how to specify an array without jQuery and without NodeLists.

Currently, I use the following, with jQuery:
`$('audio')` and then iterate over each `<audio>` element and this definitely works. I iterate over this array with a conventional for-loop, or even using the `.each` construct.

However, in an attempt to avoid jQuery and without nodeLists, I am totally clueless.

How I wish `document.querySelectorAll("audio")` would be a non-jQuery equivalent of `$('audio')`, but it does not appear to be. `querySelectorAll("audio")` and `getElementsByTagName("audio")` generate NodeLists. Not only that, but ***"audio" is not considered a tag***. *Am I to add a class or even a name* to each `<audio>` and use the specified class or name as a selector?

Help is definitely needed ... and very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Thought I'd answer seeing as you mentioned my post :)

There are a few ways you can parse a NodeList into an Array, covered in the post.

Best bet is to create a reusable function that handles the conversion for you:

```
function $$(selector, scope) {
    return [].slice.call((scope || document).querySelectorAll('div'));
}
```

Usage:

```
$$('.elem'); // document > .elem
$$('.elem', '.parent'); // .parent > .elem
```

Good luck!

Comment: Todd ... I really learned from your Post and I am very, very grateful.  What I did not learn is why convert?  In your Post, you start with an empty Array =[] and then push each extracted NodeListItem onto(into) this Array, one NodeListItem after another.  SO, each ArrayItem appears to be identical to each NodeListItem.  If the ArrayItem's are identical to the NodeListItem's, why convert?  UNLESS, the Array's method "push(...)" first converts the pushed NodeListItem to an ArrayListItem.