# Include styles for Javascript and include other styles for non-Javascript

Tags: javascript, css

I just learned a lot about how to avoid inclusion of "jQuery-min.js". The reason I thought I needed jQuery was to use $('someTag'). That was the **only** jQuery call I had in my document.

So I buckled down and learned a little about `NodeLists` for the purpose of using `document.getElementsByTagName`.  See [Specify an array without jQuery and without NodeLists [SOLVED .. I think?]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31557252/specify-an-array-without-jquery-and-without-nodelists-solved-i-think)

Now, I've come across Modernizer in my effort to include certain styles for Javascript and other styles for non-Javascript.

Obviously its size is microscopic compared to jQuery-min.js ... but it is **another file** I need to include. Besides, the presence of Modernizer eliminates a bunch of older Browsers that might still be used. Heaven knows "non-js" and "js" classes are very appealing ... but **another file**??

So ... without Modernizer, how can I include certain styles for Javascript and other styles for non-Javascript??  `display:none` and `display:block` are neat, but I need to dynamically switch back and forth depending on the presence of Javascript.

Contribution of ideas would be awesome!

Comment: check out `querySelector` and `querySelectorAll` too btw, they do css selectors and return elements. Supported since IE8 natively.

Answer (score 2):

You can write a single line of Javascript code to add a CSS class to your `<body>` element:

```
document.body.classList.add('js');
```

Comment: This works for modern browsers.  If you're super concerned about backwards-compatibility, you can do `document.body.setAttribute('class', document.body.getAttribute('class') + ' js')`

Comment: or even simpler, `document.body.className += '"js";` should work waaaay back.

Comment: @AdamD.Ruppe: You forgot a space.

Comment: yeah, classList is missing in some surprisingly recent browsers... i think it's universal now, but wasn't just a couple years ago...